# Two UITapGestureRecognizer in on UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add to my `UIViewController` :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture2:)];
tapGesture2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];
[tapGesture2 release];
```

the problem is if the user tap twice the two methods are called,and i want that if the user make double tap only the first(handleTapGesture) will be called and if he make one tap it will call only the second one(handleTapGesture2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this one..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture2)];
tapGesture2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[tapGesture2 requireGestureRecognizerToFail: tapGesture];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];
[tapGesture2 release];
```

Comment: thx for the help, i have another problem that i have buttons on the UIViewController and when i use your code the buttons call this method instead to the button method,any idea why?

Comment: use this delegate


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
 
    if ((touch.view == YourButton)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: i add UIView to the UIViewController, and add the UITapGestureRecognizer to this view,and now it work without any problem, Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the code i posted on [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture)
in this the method `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` is used in `viewcontroller.m` this will solve your problem